# Is it impossible to draw a figure which has different number of axes in the row by row(or column by column) in 'subplots'(Not 'subplot')?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]
[Site about comparing method to draw figure](https://towardsdatascience.com/master-the-art-of-subplots-in-python-45f7884f3d2e)

I want to draw above graph or below graph by using 'subplots', not subplot or other library.

You can see the below graph has one axes in first row, and two axes in second row. (i.e. this graph has the different number of axes with the row by row.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.normal(100)
b = np.random.normal(23,230,100)
c = np.random.normal(100,530,100)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.hist(a)
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.hist(b)
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.hist(c)
plt.show()
```

The reason why I want to use 'subplots' is that there is lots of useful thing, like 'sharex, sharey', 'subplots_adjust(wspace=0)', etc.

But I can not find drawing above two graphs by using 'subplots', so I want to ask it is impossible to draw these with 'subplots'.

If it is impossible, I should draw by using 'add_subplot', 'subplot2grid'. But in the situation, how can I use the function similar with 'sharex, sharey', 'subplots_adjust(wspace=0)'?

Comment: For complicated layout, `gridspec` is your friend: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/arranging_axes.html

Comment: Also, you can still use `sharex` with `add_subplot`, e.g. `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2,sharex=ax1)`.

Comment: You should use `subplot_mosiac`. It is the official method in matplotlib.  
(https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/provisional/mosaic.html,  https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html)

Comment: subplot_mosaic is a very useful tool, I see. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/arranging_axes.html This link is really helpful as others also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hideto Thank you for the good link. And I have a question. How to remove the gap between subplots? like (wspace = 0 , hspace = 0).

Comment: @Hideto You don't need to answer it. I found it just put "subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)" in the last line. It is exactly what I want to find. It may be subplots_adjust affect "subplot_mosaic".